# How to get a string after the LAST "/" character?

Tags: bash

I am trying to get a string after the last "/" character. The thing is, the number of "/" can differ. Examples:

```
Desktop/Picures/test.txt -> test.txt
Templates/DIR1/DIR2/DIR2/test2 -> test2
d1/d2/d3/d4/d5/d6 -> d6
```

...And so on, you get the idea. How can I achieve this? (btw, I need to set the result to a variable too.)

Comment: `basename` should be all you need.  e.g. `basename Templates/DIR1/DIR2/DIR2/test2` returns `test2`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski not quite.. Unless I'm doing someting wrong? I tried doing it like this - new_variable=$basename "$variable" and then I echoed it like this - echo "this is" $new_variable, but all I get is "this is" and nothing after that. (variable contains the string I want to edit)

Comment: @nana The syntax for that would be `new_variable=$(basename "$variable")`. See [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Comment: @thatotherguy oh okay thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parameter expansion.

```sh
for path in Desktop/Picures/test.txt \
            Templates/DIR1/DIR2/DIR2/test2 \
            d1/d2/d3/d4/d5/d6 ; do
    echo "${path##*/}"
done
```

`##*/` removes the longest matching pattern from the left. The pattern is `*/`, i.e. it will remove everything up to the last slash.

Comment: Note that this is slightly different from `basename "$path"` -- if the variable *ends with* "/", this'll give the empty string, while `basename` will return the last non-empty path element (e.g. `basename /path/to/dir/` will print "dir").